# creating a Yii calculator

Tags: yii

I'm new to Yii and MVC, and still trying to figure things out.

I am trying to create a calculator in Yii, below is my file directory for my calculators modules.

[image]

Now in my **DefaultController.php** I have this

```
<?php

    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {

        public function actions() {
           return array(
                'page' => array('class' => 'CViewAction'),
            );
        }

        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $this->render('index');
        }

        public function actionLoanCalculator()
        {
            /* loan calculations goes here?? */
        }

    }
```

And in my **CalculatorsModule.php**

```
<?php

class CalculatorsModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        // this method is called when the module is being created
        // you may place code here to customize the module or the application

        // import the module-level models and components
        $this->setImport(array(
            'calculators.models.*',
            'calculators.components.*',
        ));

            $model = new CalculatorsForm();

    }

    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {
        if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
        {
            // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
            // you may place customized code here
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my **loan-calculator.php**

```
<div class="form-box ">
    <div class="form-body">
        <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'calc-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                'validateOnChange'=>true,
            ),
        )); ?>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'price'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'price', array('class'=> 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>              

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'downpayment'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'downpayment', array('class'=> 'form-control')); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block')); ?>
        </div>

        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>    
    </div><!-- form -->
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

in my **models/CalculatorsForm.php** folder i have this

```
<?php

class CalculatorsForm extends CFormModel
{

    public $price;
    public $downpayment;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * title is required
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(

               );
    }

    /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'price'=>'Price',
            'downpayment'=>'Down Payment',
        );
    }

}

?>
```

Using ajax, how would I get the input from my **loan-calculator.php** calculate it in the backend and send the results back to **loan-calculator.php**

I know i could use JavaScript, but i do not want to share my calculation formula's.

Secondly i'm getting this error when viewing **domainname.com/dev/loan-calculator**

```
Undefined variable: model
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want send it via ajax you need a new action in your controller that receives your data and does the calculation and returns the result.

Comment: which is `public function actionLoanCalculator()` right? how does Yii know which action to use?

Comment: I would create a new action for the ajax call. Well - I do not know if you want do it with ajax or just submit the data and return the value.

Comment: yes i want to do it with ajax. and populate a `<div>` with the returned results

Comment: Well, than you create a function like `actionAjaxcalc()` and send the data via ajax to this controller/action and return the value and then do the rest with javascript. It's like every common ajax request beside the fact that you need to create an action function in your prefered controller for it.

Comment: i'm getting an undefined $model in my loan-calculator.php :\

Comment: When do you get this error? This php should not be touched when you do the ajax request.

Comment: when i go to `domainname.com/dev/loan-calculator` i get that error

Comment: Sorry, but I think there is a huge lack of knowledge how to run it at all. Do you need to use Yii? Maybe you can do it with a simple solution?

Comment: currently migrating my none framework site to Yii. Kind of learning Yii as i code it :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51337/discussion-between-jurik-and-user2636556)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ajaxSubmitButton`:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail

You can use this to send the form data to your action and then post back some result and use it with Javascript.

Should look something like this:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('blah txt', array('/default/loanCalculator'), array(
        'success' => 'function(data) {
            // 'data' will be the output of the loanCalculator action
        }',
    ));
?>
```

Comment: `Undefined variable: model ` need to figure out this before i proceed or can even try your suggestion. any ideas?

Comment: Yep, before you can use `$model` in your loan-calculator.php you should first create it. so: `$model = new CalculatorsForm();`

Comment: where? i put it in the calculatorsModules.php `public function init()
 {
  // this method is called when the module is being created
  // you may place code here to customize the module or the application

  // import the module-level models and components
  $this->setImport(array(
   'calculators.models.*',
   //'calculators.components.*',
  ));
  
  $model = new CalculatorsForm();
 }` same error